# Call react component from javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i have that big project and everything is on pure javascript like Class.create...prototype and functions that render every component on that page and in render with react.I mean when i type function.createElement("div") somehow it create react div.. and so on and everything is on PURE javascript .. so my question is how can i create file with normal react components and and call that react component from that js file? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question is that you need to reuse the react component. For that you need to do two things

1. Export you react component.You can do it as

   ```
   module.exports = App;
   ```

   if your react component is like `var App = React.createClass()`
2. Secondly in your other react component where you want to reuse this component you can import it as

   ```
   import {App} from './path/to/resuable/component';
   ```
3. Now use this component in the `render() {}` function as `<App/>`

Comment: Its not exactly what i want but its close ..For example i have that 
this.createDialog = new CreateDialog(.....);
this.createDialog.className="someClass";

Comment: this.dialog = createElement("div"); ... something like that and that is in some function like createDialog:function(){}... and from that function i want to call some react component

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share your code and show what you are trying to export

Comment: I dont want to create component like that createElement.. and so on

Comment: Chat ? for few minutes

Comment: You might want to look at the JSX style of writing react components where you can define a div like `var Div = <div className="xyz">Hello World</div>` and then `return Div` from the function

Comment: send me the chat link. I will see if I can open it on my network

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126583/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-freakprogrammer).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126583/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-freakprogrammer